# Calling ssh with otp from a script

Tags: bash, ssh, one-time-password

My company uses a OTP over ssh (One Time Password) to access our production machines.  The interaction might look something like this:

```
$ ssh prod
otp-md5 942 st9621 extResponse:
```

At this point I run a Java program to generate the OTP response using the info I get from SSH.  **Note:** that the hash from the ssh output ("942 st9621" in this example) has to be passed to the command bellow as input.  This hash changes everytime you ssh.

```
$ java -jar jop.jar 942 st9621 <password>
LAD DARN BHOY TEST ACHE JUTE
```

Now I cut and paste the OTP generated ("LAD DARN BHOY TEST ACHE JUTE") into the other console window.

So, just to make everything clear: I piece of data generated from the ssh command needs to be used when running jop combined with my password, and then the result passed back to the, still running, ssh command.

I would love to automate this process.  Basically, have a bash script which takes a hostname, asks for a password, and then calls ssh, passes the otp-md5 code to jop, and then the OTP back to ssh.  A nice to have is to **not** have to type my password as a command line argument since this would then be stored in the command history, and is a big security problem.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You should really consider using SSH keys instead of OTP if you want everything automated.

Comment: Yeah, I don't really have control over our setup.  I am just a lowly user, trying to get by in a shrug and a smile ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the excellent answer posted by glenn jackman:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

# Get host from command line
set host     [lindex $argv 0]

# Read password from the user
send_user "Password: "
# Turn off echo to hide password
stty -echo
expect -re "(.+)\n"
set password $expect_out(1,string)
# Turn echo back on
stty echo

# SSH into server
spawn ssh "$host"
expect -re {otp-md5 ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) extResponse: *$} {
    set otp [exec java -jar jop.jar $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) "$password"]
    send_user "\n$otp"
    send -- "$otp\r"
}
interact
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested. An expect script might be something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set otp [exec java -jar jop.jar 942 st9621 [lindex $argv 0]]
spawn ssh prod
expect -re {extResponse: *$}
send -- "$otp\r"
interact
```

You'd use that like: `optssh.exp <password>`

Responding to update, still untested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn ssh prod
expect -re {otp-md5 ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) extResponse: *$} {
    set otp [exec java -jar jop.jar $expect_out(1,string) $expect_out(2,string) [lindex $argv 0]]
    send -- "$otp\r"
}
interact
```

Comment: I've clarified my question.  In this example the md5 hash ("942 st9621"). It would need to come from the call to "ssh".

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good start.  I'll develop it and post a tested solution.

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) for interacting with SSH.